# Ruby on rails accessing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm learning Ruby and just struggling to get my head round associations properly.

I have `questions`, `sections`, and then a `question_sections` table which links the two. A question can belong to multiple sections, and a section can have many questions. Each question is given a `weight` and an `order` per section (which is stored in the `question_sections` table).

Here are my controllers:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sections, :through => :question_sections
    belongs_to :section
    has_many :question_sections
    default_scope { order(order: :asc) }

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :section, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_sections, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions, :through => :question_sections
    has_many :question_sections
    has_many :feedbacks

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :feedbacks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class QuestionSection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :section
    belongs_to :question

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :section, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I want to be able to access the data in the question_sections table from showing the questions.

In my 'show' for questions I have:

```
  <%= @question.question %>
  <%= @question.question_section.weight %>
```

But i'm getting:

```
undefined method `question_section' for #<Question:0x007fda20c72cc8>
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sooo? Your question has many `question_sections`, yet you're trying to access some singular `question_section`. Even if it were to work (magically), which one of the many should it be? And why?

Comment: Ahh, of course! So I would need to loop through the question_sections and then output the value.

In another instance I will know the sections id, how could I use that to find the correct row in my questions_section table.

Comment: Use `detect` with a block, for example. `@question.question_sections.detect{|qc| qc.section_id == my_section_id }`. Or `@question.question_sections.where(section_id: my_section_id).first`

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change the below code:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sections, :through => :question_sections
    has_many :question_sections
    default_scope { order(order: :asc) }

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :section, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_sections, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

& for accesssing data , use `<%= @question.question_sections.first.weight %>`

This is because question sections is an array of hash

Comment: `question_sections` is neither an array, not does it contain hashes :)

Comment: it is ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy which contains array of hash

Comment: Nope, not hashes. CollectionProxy _behaves like_ array, in some ways, but it is not an array and does not _contain_ one.